# NetworkManager not allowing scan of available wifi APs

Tags: linux, systemd, networkmanager

I'm running buildroot Linux with systemd and NetworkManager and I'm trying to get on a Wifi network. I'm running a scan and get an error. Using NetworkManager I run the following:

```
# nmcli radio wifi on
# nmcli dev wifi rescan
Error: Scanning not allowed while unavailable or activating.

# nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
eth1    ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1
eth0    ethernet  unavailable  --
usb0    ethernet  unavailable  --
can0    can       unmanaged    --
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
wlan0   wifi      unmanaged    --
```

NetworkManager is active

```
# systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-06-22 11:27:31 UTC; 14min ago
```

Any ideas on what to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was that wpa_supplicant was not running.

```
systemctl start wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: thank you, works for me on Fedora Server